# How to map only specific services to a specific listener port in ALB (k8s ingress)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-elb

For example, guestbook-ui service and bbs-ui service are installed in k8s.

And I want to map guestbook-ui only to the 8080 listener port and bbs-ui service to the 8081 listener port to the pre-generated k8s ALB ingress.

However, if you write and store the following in spec, all guestbook-ui and bbs-ui services are deployed to all ports of 8080, 8081, and routing is twisted.

```yaml
# skip

metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP":8080}, {"HTTP":8081}]'

# skip

spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: bbs-ui
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: guestbook-ui
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

How can I deploy the service to the listener port I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a feature to automatically merge multiple ingress rules for all ingresses in the same **ingress group**. The AWS ALB ingress controller supports them with a single ALB.

```yaml
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: my-group
```

> In the AWS ALB ingress controller, prior to version 2.0, each ingress object you created in Kubernetes would get its own ALB. Customers wanted a way to lower their cost and duplicate configuration by sharing the same ALB for multiple services and namespaces.
> By sharing an ALB, you can still use annotations for advanced routing but share a single load balancer for a team, or any combination of apps by specifying the alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name annotation. **All services with the same group.name will use the same load balancer**.

So, you can create ingress like this:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress1
  namespace: mynamespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: mytag=tag
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: my-group
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 8080}]'
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: bbs-ui
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific

---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress2
  namespace: mynamespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: mytag=tag
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: my-group
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 8081}]'
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: guestbook-ui
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

You can read more info about [IngressGroup here](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.0/guide/ingress/annotations/#ingressgroup).